# Python - Passing a function with multiple arguments into another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this method that I want to pass *into* another function.

```py
def get_service_enums(context, enum):
   svc = Service(context)
   return svc.get_enum(enum)
```

I want to pass this function is as a parameter to another class.

```
ColumnDef(enum_values=my_func)
```

Ideally, `my_func` is `get_service_enums`. However `get_service_enums` has a second parameter, `enum` that I want to pass in at same time I pass in `get_service_enums`. How can I do this without actually invoking `get_service_enums` with parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

using [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) from functools to create a new function that only takes the first argument.

```py
from functools import partial

def get_service_enums(context, enum):
    print(context, enum)

partial_function = partial(get_service_enums, enum="second_thing")
partial_function("first_thing")
```

```
first_thing second_thing
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it not work for you to pass the function and its argument separately

```py
ColumnDef(enum_values=get_service_enums, enum)
```

with the class `ColumnDef` in charge of passing in `enum` when the function is invoked?

If not, [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is your friend:

```py
import functools

# New version of get_service_enums with enum = 42
my_func = functools.partial(get_service_enums, enum=42)
my_func('hello')  # hello, 42

ColumnDef(enum_values=my_func)
```

Comment: for your first suggestion, if `ColumnDef` has multiple constructor arguments would the syntax look like 
`ColumnDef(name='A', data_type='B', enum_values=(get_service_enums, enum), db_col_name='D')`
? I wasn't aware that python allows you to pass in a function and its argument separately.